# Which JavaScript frameworks currently support loading ther modules with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm currently using MooTools, but I want to start some developments using RequireJS module loading. Is there any other framework that supports RequireJS module loading out-of-the-box? I've heard Dojo 1.7 will, but it's still under development. Any other options?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [jQuery 1.7](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) support.
- [MooTools 2.0](https://github.com/kamicane/mootools-core/compare/2.0...define-2) will supoort soon.
- Dojo 1.7 support (but have some modules conflicts, like `text` module)
- [ExtJS 4](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) Not support RequireJS but have a built-in lazy-load solution for it modules.

You can add support for modules from any framework you want. If the framework don't have support to RequireJS, you can make a wrapper file to load the framework.

[Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) wrapper file exemple:

```
define(['lib/zepto'], function() {
    require(['lib/zepto']);
    return this.Zepto;
});
```

In your application you define the route for [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) in the wrapper file and let it load the lib.

Main application file exemple:

```
require({paths: { 'zepto': 'wrapper/zepto' } });
```

So your application files structure will be something like this:

```
main.js
lib/zepto.js
wrapper/zepto.js
```

So any framework can support RequireJS, but you will need to write some wrappers for modules that don't added support for [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) loaders.

**EDIT 09/07/2012:**

The RequireJS 2.+ has a new feature called `shim` that make possible to use any browser based framework with it.

And new feature to make wrappers to server-side non-AMD require proposal from CommonJS patterns.

Comment: Notice that I don't want to load the entire library, that can be done with every framework. I want to load specific components of the framework, but not the whole and I think that the framework should provide AMD support for that...

Comment: The wrapper is useful when the framework don't have support, like zepto. Zepto is a framework, but, you can apply for almost anything like specific components. I'm using wrappers to load Backbone and Underscore as it component. Both don't support AMD.

Comment: Let's say you only want to load the AJAX module from Zepto, how do you make a wrapper for that? Will it work without loading the whole of the framework?

Comment: If you require the core only, you can append the module to your global var from the framework you are using. Like in zepto you will need to include the core wrapper in require files from ajax module wrapper. You need to declare the var like "var Zepto = this.Zepto" before require the module, it will mixim with Zepto Core. Use only if you realy need to use an unsupported AMD framework.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but really need a framework that supports AMD to prevent support issues.

Comment: Also, MooTools 2 and Dojo 1.7 are WIP (work in progress) yet, and jQuery is not an option for me. Seems that I still have to wait some time...

Comment: Mabe an good solution for you is to use [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) it's a dual license framework, very complete that has built-in support for lazy-load modules. It's not requirejs, but works great. And have very nice and easy documentation with lots of modules.

Comment: Dojo Toolkit 1.7 just released and has AMD support. Accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MooTools 2.0 does, checkout the branch under the MooTools repo on Github.

Comment: MooTools 2.0 is still WIP (work in progress). I need a stable version.

Comment: Update: MooTools Core will be packaged into AMD compliant modules in 1.5, that is about 1 month away ;)